# Disk size much larger than used + available space

Tags: disk-usage, lvm

After extending my LVM I got a mismatch when using `df -kh`.

```
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% 
/dev/mapper/Data-Media   11T  5,1T  5,3T  49%
```

However the usage is correct. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This could be a simple rounding error. Show us the output in megabytes.

Comment: It is a rounding error. @meskobalazs bytes would be even better >:-D

Comment: Yeah, but I'd rather not use a calculator, if it is not neccessary :)

Comment: What meskobalazs said, but it still could be not enough. If you want to do the math precisely use bytes: `df -k -B 1`

Comment: Thanks guys! Here is it is in bytes. `/dev/mapper/Data-Media 11907648708608 5501401092096 5806113181696  49%`

Comment: I deleted my answer, because not even using bytes makes those numbers right. I don't understand how `df` is doing those calculations. This is what I get: `11907648708608 B * 49 / 100 = 5834747867217.92 / 1024^4 T = 5.3066722714155912 T =~ 5.3T` and `11907648708608 B * 51 / 100 = 6072900841390.08 / 1024^4 T = 5.5232711396366358 =~ 5.5T`

Comment: Okay I was reading wrong. Your last awnser makes sense now! Thanks for the help!